# Can I configure code_swarm to only create the png files sans visual display?

Tags: java, code-visualization, code-swarm

Is there a way to configure code_swarm to only create the .png files. I think it would speed up the processing if it wasn't trying to display as it created the images.

I've looked in the FAQ, but didn't notice anything about that in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, it probably would speed things up, though I suspect not by as much as you might hope.  There's an open issue about this in the official issue tracker: http://code.google.com/p/codeswarm/issues/detail?id=37

To summarize: last time I checked, Processing.org – the library we use for drawing – doesn't support running in headless mode.  A couple of people have looked into doing it without much luck.  If your only concern is performance, I wouldn't worry about this.  If it's running too slow, might I suggest my own fork of the project, it's remarkably faster (yes, I do intend on integrating it back into the main svn repo sometime): http://github.com/rictic/code_swarm/

Comment: Thanks for the link. It seems to get broken from here to there, but I was able to find the right page from the 404 on github. My *_activity.xml file is 101Mb, and will get bigger, is there a way to estimate the time that will take?

Comment: Wow that IS a great deal faster. Thanks!

Comment: @Peter: I found a good speed up for the draw history routine, I tried posting it as an issue on github, but I keep getting an error. And your blog has no way to leave feedback (that I could see).

Comment: Ok, it's a shame that the issues system isn't working on github. I wasn't able to reproduce your error.  You can send me a diff, I'm rictic at gmail.  If you know your way around git, you could also fork my repo, apply your patch, and I could merge your changes in with one click. Either way is fine with me.